# Minimize need for sudo

Tags: command-line, sudo

Very often I need to use the `sudo` command because the command I'm running needs higher privileges. Is there some method to minimize the usage of `sudo` and/or a way to use it that's faster than typing my password, but which is still secure?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many operations and programs do not in themselves need sudo, only for access to certain files. These files often also allow access for a group (e.g. /dev/mixer for group audio on my Debian), and you can avoid the sudo if you add your user to that group. The strace command is a good tool to find out which files are the problem; just look for an open() call that returns a negative value aside from -1.

If you need the sudo command for specific applications (a classic for me being pbuilder, which needs to chroot), it might be a good idea to insert that command and the NOPASSWD flag into /etc/sudoers. That isn't the most secure way (the root user inside the pbuilder environment can do all sorts of crap), but better than typing your password in normal system use and getting used to that.

Comment: +1 for the point about looking closely to group ownerships.

Comment: ...and do consider setting up your own groups for specific tasks (and applying config to the relevant daemons where appropriate - e.g. sshd, cupsd)

Answer (score 3):

If you are *not* a sysadmin then most of the times you use sudo is a indicator that some user rights in the system is wrong. A normal user should not need sudo for the daily work. sudo is for installing new applications and hardware.

So think *why* you use sudo. 
Also think about if you can change something so you don't need to use sudo the next time, or if this is a valid usecase for sudo.

Comment: I'm installing often, I'm using command that need sudo (mv, cp, cpufreq-selector), editing system files. Many times I have to use sudo and type password.

Comment: @xralf then you can consider yourself what Johan described as *sysadmin*. But frankly, I believe the truth lies somewhere in between: Being a sysadmin is not a binary qualifier. You can be more of a sysadmin then some people and at the some time much less then some other.

Answer (score 3):

Authentication is an important aspect of system administration. You *should* get used to it. I know that nowadays people try to be more lazy and avoid remembering and typing passwords, but this approach has to lead a decreased security, unless you use some other reasonable authentication method like fingerprint reader.

If you often need to run a number of commands as root, maybe you should use `su -` instead of `sudo` in such situations. But remember to log out from root after you've finished or when you go away from the computer - this has to be learned as a habit. You may also consider locking the console using a tool like `vlock` or within a `screen` session.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the `timestamp_timeout` property to whatever value you want. This controls how long the password is 'cached'. See the `sudoers(5)` man page.

> ```
>   timestamp_timeout
>                    Number of minutes that can elapse before sudo will ask
>                    for a passwd again.  The timeout may include a
>                    fractional component if minute granularity is
>                    insufficient, for example 2.5.  The default is 5.  Set
>                    this to 0 to always prompt for a password.  If set to a
>                    value less than 0 the user's timestamp will never
>                    expire.  This can be used to allow users to create or
>                    delete their own timestamps via sudo -v and sudo -k
>                    respectively.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

sudo -s

works, but bad idea, if you do wrong command sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I often sudo bash, same as su I suppose